# Calculate time intervals with custom start/end points

Tags: python, r

I have a few datasets each of which has time intervals as following:

```
        configStartDate            configEndDate
2012-06-07 10:38:01.000  2012-06-11 13:35:25.000
2012-07-12 20:00:55.000  2012-07-17 10:17:53.000
2012-07-18 12:44:15.000  2012-07-20 02:15:47.000
2012-07-20 02:15:47.000  2012-10-05 10:35:19.000
2012-10-05 10:35:19.000  2012-11-13 10:44:24.000
```

I need to write a query function (in R, but I am just figuring out the logic right now; prototyping in Python) which would take two custom start and end dates and sum up the intervals in between.

The issue is that the query dates could start in the middle, or outside of the time chunks. So, for instance, in the above example, my query could be for time interval 2012-06-09 and 2012-11-11, in which case I’d have to modify the start and end dates of the first and last chunk. But, the first interval could also start in the middle of the second chunk, etc., etc.

The code to add up chunks is trivial:

```
diff_days = (pd.to_datetime(df_41.configEndDate) - pd.to_datetime(df_41.configStartDate)).astype('timedelta64[h]') / 24
print(sum(diff_days))

# 126.541666667 days
```

But now I am looking for the most efficient way to do the custom query starts and ends.

Right now what I am thinking is:

Loop through each `configStartDate`, `configEndDate` combination:

If `query_start` is before the particular chunk’s end date, set that chunk as the first to be included in the calculation and set its start date as the max(`query_start`, `current_start_date`). Exit the loop.

Then do the same but opposite for the `query_end` (replace the chunk's end date with start date, before with after, and maximum with minimum). Set that chunk as the last to be included for the calculation. Exit the loop.

In R-style pseudocode, it would look like:

```
ix = which(end_date > start_query)[1]
start_date[ix] = max(start_date[ix], start_query)
chunk[ix] -> first chunk

repeat with end_query, opposite signs
```

Is there an easier way to implement this? (I am not looking for the specific code help; just the logic advise.) Thanks.

Comment: Your method seems pretty sound. Personally, what I'd do differently is just subset the data right off the bat by your intervals.

Comment: Well, the data is already subsetted that way. As, in, events that have a certain software version on them (installed during those intervals) occur only during those intervals. But, I need to normalize the frequency of events by software installation times.

Comment: I more meant further subset the data by your start_date and end_date values, but it truthfully does not matter.