# Speed up line-by-line interval update/addition in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, intervals

This is the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914114/calculate-time-intervals-with-custom-start-end-points?noredirect=1#comment53657537_32914114), but now I am interested in speeding up my function. I will copy-paste the problem description and my R code, which is running about 36 msec per row, which ends up too long for the number of rows I have.

Problem:

I have a few datasets each of which has time intervals as following:

```
        configStartDate            configEndDate
2012-06-07 10:38:01.000  2012-06-11 13:35:25.000
2012-07-12 20:00:55.000  2012-07-17 10:17:53.000
2012-07-18 12:44:15.000  2012-07-20 02:15:47.000
2012-07-20 02:15:47.000  2012-10-05 10:35:19.000
2012-10-05 10:35:19.000  2012-11-13 10:44:24.000
```

I need to write a query function (in R, but I am just figuring out the logic right now; prototyping in Python) which would take two custom start and end dates and sum up the intervals in between.

The issue is that the query dates could start in the middle, or outside of the time chunks. So, for instance, in the above example, my query could be for time interval 2012-06-09 and 2012-11-11, in which case I’d have to modify the start and end dates of the first and last chunk. But, the first interval could also start in the middle of the second chunk, etc., etc.

R code:

```
# calculating time differences row-by-row:
soft_days <- soft_days[, 
  .(soft_days = calc_sw_intervals(soft_dt = soft_install_model, 
                                  start_query = start_q,
                                  end_query = end_q,
                                  assetID = assetId,
                                  soft_mm = soft_major_minor), 
  by = c('assetId', 'soft_major_minor')
]


# code to sum up (custom) time intervals:
calc_sw_intervals <- function(soft_dt, start_query, end_query, assetID, soft_mm, dType = 1){
  start_query <- ymd(start_query)
  end_query <- ymd(end_query)

  soft_dt <- soft_dt[assetId == assetID & soft_major_minor %in% soft_mm
                                  & configEndDate > start_query
                                  & configStartDate < end_query
                                  & deviceType == dType
                                  ,list(configStartDate, configEndDate)
                                  ]

  if(dim(soft_dt)[1] == 0)
    return(NaN)

  soft_dt[1, configStartDate := max(start_query, configStartDate)]
  soft_dt[.N, configEndDate := min(end_query, configEndDate)]

  total_days <- soft_dt[, sum(as.numeric(difftime(configEndDate, configStartDate, units = 'days')))]
  return(total_days)
}
```

What the code does is find all time intervals where the end of the interval is > `start_query`, beginning of the interval is < `end_query`; then it updates the beginning and the end of the first/last intervals if needed (if the query start and end are within the first and last intervals), and sums up the time differences within the intervals.

Any sort of clever speed-up would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `?foverlaps`

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
library(dplyr)
calc_sw_intervals <- function(df, start, end){
  df %>% 
    filter(start < configEndDate, configStartDate < end) %>%
    mutate(
      delta = pmin(configEndDate, end) - pmax(configStartDate, start)
    ) %>%
    summarise(Total = sum(delta))
}
```